# How to enable "Direct Rendering Display Compositor" in Chrome on Windows 11?

Tags: google-chrome

I have [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRy8b.png) most of the hw acceleration options (GTX 1060). But despite the added `#enable-drdc` flag `Direct Rendering Display Compositor` is [not enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T99OV.png). So, the question is in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I find a conversation about this in https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/ozone-reviews/c/woK87jkJj_Y?pli=1

It seems that this feature is disabled excluding Android P.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).